# Diagonal pullback on product cohomology space

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology, de-rham-cohomology

I was recently introduced to the de Rham cohomology and while we were given a basic overview, there were no hints to a bigger context. As I found the little insight we got extremely interesting, I'm trying to delve deeper (recommendations for literature will be highly appreciated).

My question relates to the cross product which we defined as follows:
Let $M,N$ be smooth manifolds. With $\pi_M$ and $\pi_N$ denoting the natural projections for the product space $M \times N$ we can define a well-defined product by:
\begin{align*}
\times : H^*(M) \times H^*(N) &\rightarrow H^*(M \times N) \\
 (\omega, \eta) &\mapsto [\omega] \times [\eta] := [\pi^*_M \omega \wedge \pi_N^* \eta ]
\end{align*}
Further we defined the wedge product via
\begin{align*}
\wedge : H^*(M) \times H^*(M) &\rightarrow H^*(M) \\
(\omega, \sigma) &\mapsto [\omega] \wedge [\sigma] = [\omega \wedge \sigma]
\end{align*}

Now given the standard diagonal embedding of $M$ via
\begin{align*}
\Delta: M &\rightarrow M \times M \\
p &\mapsto (p,p)
\end{align*}
I want to prove that for $\omega, \eta \in H^*(M)$
$$ \omega \wedge \eta = \Delta^* (\omega \times \eta) $$
holds true. Those are my thoughts so far:

\begin{align*}
(\omega \times \eta) &= (\pi^*_M \omega \wedge \pi^*_M\eta) \\
\Rightarrow \Delta^*(\omega \times \eta) &= \Delta^*(\pi^*_M \omega \wedge \pi^*_M\eta) = \Delta^*(\pi^*_M (\omega \wedge \eta))
\end{align*}
Now while I see that
$$ \Delta^*\pi^*_M: \Omega^*(M) \rightarrow \Omega^*(M \times M) \rightarrow \Omega^*(M) $$
My question is, if the above is correct and if so, why
$$ \Delta^*\pi^*_M = id_{\Omega^*(M)}$$
holds true. Maybe I'm just missing something obvious here ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$\Delta$ is a section of $\pi_M$, *ie.*, $\pi_M \circ \Delta = \text{id}_M$. Use contravariance of pullbacks to conclude that $\Delta^*\pi_M^* = \text{id}_{\Omega^*(M)}$.

Comment: I missed the _'recommendation for literature'_ part. I am reading Tu's _"Introduction to Manifolds"_, I find it pretty good, and it has a detailed discussion on de Rham cohomology.

Comment: Thank you for your help! The remark about $\Delta$ being a section of the induced fibre bundles really opened my eyes. I'll have a thorough look at your book recommendation.

Answer (score 2):

You really need two $\pi_M$'s to sort this out. The point is that $\Delta^*\pi_1^*\omega = \omega$ and $\Delta^*\pi_2^*\eta = \eta$. Thus, $$\Delta^*(\omega\times\eta) = \Delta^*(\pi_1^*\omega\wedge\pi_2^*\eta) = \omega\wedge\eta$$
because pullback commutes with wedge product.

Comment: I assume the two versions of $\pi_M$ are needed due to the projection on the left or right component? Together with feynhat's remark about $\Delta$ being a section of the fibre bundle induced by the projections, I understand the proof. Thank you very much!